# Using Regex find a specific string followed by two strings separated with spaces

Tags: regex, attributes, sdp

I am trying to find a quick way to extract info from a longer string. In particular, I am working with an SDP body and the string in question is:

```
    "v=0
    o=111 843670094 843670094 IN IP4 192.168.1.101
    s=-
    c=IN IP4 192.168.1.101
    t=0 0
    a=sendrecv
    m=audio 6000 RTP/AVP 8 0 101
    a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
    a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
    a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
    a=fmtp:101 0-15
    a=ptime:20"
```

From the above-given string, I would like to find line 'c=IN IP4 192.168.1.101' and then match 2 strings that follow "c=IN". In my case, these would be words marked "**IP4**" and "**192.168.1.101**"

In real life, the second word can be {"IP4"|"IP6"} and the second word can be an FQDN but normally it is an IP address. Each 'line' in the given string ends with '\r\n' characters. I am giving this info cause that can simplify a way to grab an IP address part.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this will work:

```
    c=IN\s(.*)\s(.*)(\r\n)
```